# Procedure or function 'SelectBuilding' expects parameter '@NameFa', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem I don't know why 
I check all of the Parameters and I Dont Miss Anything!
error : Procedure or function 'SelectBuilding' expects parameter '@NameFa', which was not supplied.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=OnlineCharge;Trusted_Connection=True;");
public DataTable Select(int Id,string NameFa, string Address, int ManagerId, short TotalUnits, int ChargeMethodID)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("NameFa", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("ManagerId", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("TotalUnits", typeof(short));
    table.Columns.Add("ChargeMethodID", typeof(int));

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectBuilding", con);
        select.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NameFa", NameFa));
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address", Address));
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ManagerId", ManagerId));
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TotalUnits", TotalUnits));
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChargeMethodID", ChargeMethodID));
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        rdr = select.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            table.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], rdr[4],rdr[5]);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

And this is procudure :

```
@Id int,
@NameFa nvarchar(150),
@Address nvarchar(MAX),
@ManagerId int,
@TotalUnits smallint,
@ChargeMethodID int
As
    Begin
        IF(@Id >0 )
            Begin
               Select * From Buildings where Id = @Id
            End
        ELSE
            Begin
                Declare @sqlTxt nvarchar(MAX)
                SET @sqlTxt = 'SELECT * FROM buildings where ID>0'
                IF(@NameFa!= null)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND NameFa Like ''%@NameFa%'''
                END
                IF(@Address!= null)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND Address Like ''%@Address%'''
                END
                IF(@ManagerId > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND ManagerId = @ManagerId'
                END
                IF(@TotalUnits > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND TotalUnits = @TotalUnits'
                END
                IF(@ChargeMethodID > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND ChargeMethodID = @ChargeMethodID'
                END
                Exec(@sqlTxt)
            End
    END
```

PLZ HELP :|

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? Clearly the `NameFa` variable is null.

Comment: @NameFa does not contains any value in that. It is null